# Count no of opportunities in the related account

Tags: apex, trigger

I want to count the no of opportunities in account and update a field in account. So far i have done this but it is updating the field with the value 0 every time.

```
trigger countOpportunity on Opportunity (after insert, after delete, after update) {
    list<Account> accList = new List<Account>();
    for(Opportunity op : trigger.new){
        Account ac = [select total_opportunities__c from account where id =: op.AccountId];
        ac.total_opportunities__c = String.valueOf(ac.opportunities.size());
        system.debug(ac.opportunities.size());
        accList.add(ac);
    }
    update accList;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a rollup summary field on Account to count the child Opportunities.

Refer [Roll-Up Summary Field](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_about_roll_up_summary_fields.htm&type=0)

Otherwise if you want to do it through trigger this is the approach:

*Note, your code is not bulkified, and you are performing SOQL within `for` loop.*

```
trigger countOpportunity on Opportunity (after insert, after delete, after update) 
{
    Set<Id> AccountIds = new Set<Id>();

    list<Account> accList = new List<Account>();
    for(Opportunity op : trigger.new)
    {
        AccountIds.add(op.AccountId;)
    }

    List<AggregateResult> lstResult = [SELECT AccountId, COUNT(Id) countId 
                                        FROM Opportunity 
                                        WHERE AccountId IN:AccountIds
                                        GROUP BY AccountId];

    List<Account> lstAccount = new List<Account>();
    for(AggregateResult result:lstResult)
    {
        Account acct = new Account (Id=(Id)result.get('AccountId'), 
                                        total_opportunity__c = (Integer)result.get('countId'));

        lstAccount.add(acct);
    }

    update lstAccount; 
}
```

Comment: You do not need to query the accounts. You can simply instantiate a new Account sObject for each Agg Result and populate the Id and Total_Opportunity__c field then do an update. Map is a good Idea, but no need since the AR is grouped by Id so you could just use a list as well

Comment: That's why I thought so, since I haven't tested thats why I was not sure, thanks for your input. Yes, updated my code now

Comment: Now that I think about it. If there are no opps for the account t after delete this will not update the total field. In your account I'd loop, use a map and instantiate a new account with a 0 total. The in Agg loop update totals. This should cover cases where last opp is deleted

Answer (score 1):

As @santanu mentioned, there is no need for apex here. Just create a standard rollup summary field to count opportunities related to an account. And your done.

Never code when config will do.